# Payment options in ios sdk without in app purchase and PayPal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a requirement in my new iPhone application, where I have to made payment like paisapay (Ebay) does. can I open a web page  where user can fill information related to payment and server will handle payment? This Transaction will be in secure manner (In standard way). is it possible? Apple will approve app?

Comment: Apple won't approve any method of payment for application content that doesn't go through the App Store.  I don't think this applies to things like physical goods, for instance, if you make an ebay client, that's OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using this means to unlock functionality in the app after payment, it will be rejected else it's okay.

As per app review guidelines

> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>   rejected
>
> 11.13  Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

For more reference please read the latest App store review guidelines at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Answer (score 3):

maybe this might help you

http://www.zooz.com/

FYI: In accordance with Apple’s App Store Guidelines, ZooZ can be used without limitation for purchasing physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application.